# Python threading, weird result

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I am testing how python threading works, I am expecting the processes to be started and finished live, but it is not what I got. Here is the simple script:

```
import threading
import time
import random


def loop_fn():
    for i in range(1, 5):
        n = random.randint(1,5)
        print "process", i," started "
        time.sleep(n)
        print "process", i," finished"

threading.Thread(target=loop_fn).start()
print "end"
```

and the result is shown **offline** and **after multiple runs** (windows environment):

```
<1st program run>
%run threading1.py
end
process 1  started 

<2nd program run>
%run threading1.py
process 1  finished
process 2  started 
process 2  finished
process 3  started 
processend 1  started 

<3rd program run>
%run threading1.py
process 3  finished
process 4  started 
process 4  finished
endprocess 1  started
```

Any hint?

Comment: You probably want something that waits for your thread to be done executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want processes one through five to run in parallel, you need to create a thread for each one, not one thread for all five. If you want the threads to finish executing before the program terminates, then the main thread should [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) each of the worker threads.

```
import threading
import time
import random

def loop_fn(i):
    n = random.randint(1,5)
    print "process", i," started "
    time.sleep(n)
    print "process", i," finished"

threads = []
for i in range(1, 5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=loop_fn, args=(i,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
print "end"
```

Result:

```
process 1  started process
 2  started process
 3process  4 started
 started
processprocess  32   finished finished

processprocess 1   finished4
 finished
end
```

---

Optionally, you may want to use a [Lock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects) for printing, if you want nicer output. This will prevent one thread from beginning to print, while another thread has halfway finished printing.

```
import threading
import time
import random

print_lock = threading.Lock()
def atomic_print(msg):
    print_lock.acquire()
    print msg
    print_lock.release()


def loop_fn(i):
    n = random.randint(1,5)
    atomic_print("process {} started ".format(i))
    time.sleep(n)
    atomic_print("process {} finished".format(i))

threads = []
for i in range(1,5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=loop_fn, args=(i,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
print "end"
```

Result:

```
process 1 started
process 2 started
process 3 started
process 4 started
process 1 finished
process 2 finished
process 4 finished
process 3 finished
end
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, you hit the nail over the head.